# How to load child route by default with lazy loading in angular 2?

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, url-routing

I know this question asked many time i have search many **SO** question but unable to find answer so just posting my question my structure is like below.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'A',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'A',
        resolve: {
            DATA: ADataResolver,
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'B',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'B',
                loadChildren: './b/b.module#BModule'
            }]
    }
]
```

now on app load i want to load path **A/B**

How will i do it ? I have done above thing and its not working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any error? have you added `router-outlet` ?

Comment: **'A'**  is a Module and **'B'** is a component of module A?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan  yes i have added when i directly put url things works

Comment: @AkashTantri  No they both are module

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if something else is wrong somewhere else. I just modified my code to (basically) match what you have and it worked fine (see below). I have movies, so that would be your "B".

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'A',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'A',
        children: [
            { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
            {
                path: 'movies',
                loadChildren: './movies/movie.module#MovieModule'
            },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'movies', pathMatch: 'full' }
        ]
    },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Navigating to `http://localhost:4200` resulting in a URL of: `http://localhost:4200/A/movies`

You can find my code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-communication/tree/master/MH-Take4

I just modified my `app-routing.module.ts` as shown above and ran it.

Comment: Have you tried to run this code bse i have setup same thing and its not working :(

Comment: Did you try to run the code from my github? It all works. I just used it in a talk I gave at a conference last week and it worked with no problem.

Comment: @DeborahK can you please have a look at my question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357145/redirectto-lazy-module-based-on-user-role.
I'm having same issue with multiple lazy-loading modules.

Answer (score 1):

Please check B module it's also required component and routing concept.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AdminComponent } from "../components/admin/admin.component";

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AdminComponent 

  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdminComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, 
     RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  bootstrap: [AdminComponent]
})
export class BModule { }
```

Comment: its already done But when i enter A it will redirect to A/B but i want by default it will goes to A/B

Comment: @Riturajratan plz try: const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'A/B',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading should be used when you want to delay the loading of one or more modules until the user requests those modules.
Looks like your scenario needs the B module by default. 
You could directly invoke the component:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'A',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'A',
        resolve: {
            DATA: ADataResolver,
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'B',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'B',
                component: 'BComponent'
            }]
    }
]
```

If it still has to be a lazy module, did you try enableTracing? Is the route getting recognized?

Comment: But when i enter A it will redirect to A/B
but i want by default it will goes to A/B

Comment: const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'A',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {path: 'A/B',
        resolve: {
            DATA: ADataResolver,
        }, component: 'BComponent'}]